# How to use d3 with and express application - reference error: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom, d3.js

In my expressjs application, I'm trying to dynamically render some vertices in a graph using d3. I am running into some problems with, I think, the order in which my code is executing. When using the d3.select function I get an error saying:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I know that node does not inherently have a document object model as it is server side, but I thought that if the web page was already rendered, I would have access to the document with d3, which is where I'm running into problems. I think that all of my express app.js functions execute before the webpage is rendered, and thus the document does not exist. Do I need to use something like jsdom if I want to use d3 on an express app? Is my flow of execution incorrect? I should note that I am reading in potentially very large files in the parsing function (up to tens of millions of lines) so I had to include promise handling to make sure I had all the data parsed before manipulating it. I'm not sure if that's a factor as well.

For reference, here are the relevant portions of my express application:

```
//----app.js----
const Render = require('./public/javascripts/render');
const Parser = require('./public/javascripts/Parser');

Parser.parseInputTabs(filename, delimiter)
    .then(function (G) {
        //G is a Graph object that I define, it's the return of the parse promise
        LH = G;
        // Lots of functions to manipulate the LH graph
        Render.render(LH);
        app.listen(3000, function () {
            console.log('\nExample app listening on port 3000!')
        });
    }



//----Render.js----
const d3 = require("d3");

function render(graph) {
    let canvas = d3.select("svg");

    graph.vertices.forEach(function (v) {
        canvas.append("circle")
            .attr("id", v.index)
            .attr("cx", v.x)
            .attr("cy", v.y)
            .attr("radius", v.radius)
            .attr("title", "Fill info in with callback")
    })
}

module.exports.render = render;


//----Parser.js----
function parseInputTabs(filename, delimiter) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         // A bunch of code to parse an input file from command line 
         // and manipulate it into a Graph object that I define in my own class
         ...
         resolve(G);

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to do most your d3 work on the front end rather than the server.

Is it possible to use the server to still parse/format your data but just send the formatted to the client and do your d3 function there?

Comment: So that would entail something like converting all my data to JSON then reading the JSON from the client side and doing the d3 rendering there?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to you can use d3 in node but because node does not have DOM you need jsdom. An example can be found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/c99a699587b5c5465228).

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const d3 = require("d3");

const setEnv = () =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      jsdom.env({
        html:'',
        features:{ QuerySelector:true }, //you need query selector for D3 to work
        done:(errors, window)=>
          errors
            ? reject(errors)
            : resolve(window)
      })
  );

function render(graph) {
  return setEnv()
  .then(
    window=>{
      window.d3 = d3.select(window.document); //get d3 into the dom
      const svg = window.d3.select("svg");

      graph.vertices.forEach(function (v) {
        svg.append("circle")
          .attr("id", v.index)
          .attr("cx", v.x)
          .attr("cy", v.y)
          .attr("radius", v.radius)
          .attr("title", "Fill info in with callback")
      });
      return window.d3.select('svg').html();    
    }
  )
}
```